# Moved site to new host and domain, all links rendering homepage?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So here is my situation:

A client of mine has a site based on CodeIgniter hosted at some shared host on domainA.com. They wanted to move the site to a new domain and new host which i have done. I created a new database, and exported the old database and imported it into the new one and i changed the baseurl in the config.php file. The site itself loads up properly.

However, whenever i click on a link that is in the form: 'domainB.com/site/someaction', they all just render or redirect to the homepage. I know PHP, but have no experience with CodeIgniter. I have no idea who created the site initially to reach out to them for assistance, so i am hoping someone on SO can shed some light on what might be happening.

I can provide any other information that might be necessary to try and figure this out. Thanks.

**update**

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

config.php:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['base_url'] = "http://www.bidcleangrow.com/";    
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
$config['url_suffix'] = "";
$config['language'] = "english";
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8";
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use
$config['log_threshold'] = 3;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
$config['encryption_key'] = "";
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';


/* End of file config.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/config/config.php *
```

Comment: Is there a base href referenced in the HTML?

Comment: Most likely some `RewriteRule` from the .htaccess are amiss.

Comment: @mario: edited question to include .htaccess

Comment: @Pete: nope, all links are absolute

Comment: if i disable the .htaccess, i get a 404 for those links, i'm guessing the .htaccess is required by CI?

Comment: @Jason Yes it is required, can you post the `config/config.php`, obviously knocking out anything sensitive, but marking it if and where you do.

Comment: @Orbling: added the config.php

Comment: I assume this is the complete .htaccess, it's not wrapped in any `<IfModule>` thingy? Else I'd think your new provider uses CGI or FastCGI and your old mod_php (or vice versa). Then you might have trouble with the `PATH_INFO` which differs between them. But no idea how/where CodeIgniter wants a config change then.

Comment: @mario If it is a `PATH_INFO` issue, then it can be altered in `system/libraries/URI.php` but it should be unnecessary, if there is no `PATH_INFO` then it moves on to `QUERY_STRING`, then `ORIG_PATH_INFO` - checking the `$_SERVER` variable and the environment too at each stage.

Comment: @Jason Can you bung a `var_dump()` in a file for test purposes?  `system/libraries/Router.php` find this line (I'm using v1.7.2) `$this->uri->_fetch_uri_string();` (first occurrence in `_set_routing()`) add `var_dump($this->uri->uri_string);` under that.

Comment: @Orbling: when i do that, i get this: string(0) ""

Comment: @Jason Right, so it is definitely not finding the path - right remove that.  In to `system/libraries/URI.php` find `_fetch_uri_string()`, `var_dump($_SERVER);` and `var_dump($_GET);` in that.

Comment: added output to question

Comment: @Jason You can remove that now, right there is no `PATH_INFO` or `QUERY_STRING`, but `ORIG_PATH_INFO` and `SCRIPT_NAME` exist, however for some reason they are identical and this is breaking things.  Comment the line with `ORIG_PATH_INFO` in it, and replace (put underneath) with `$path = $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'];`.

Comment: @Jason Almost done, just broke the error checking with that change.  Set that line we changed to `$path = (isset($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] : '');` so that it still works on the homepage.

Comment: yup i just figured that out too, everything is working great now, thanks so much! :)

Comment: @Jason Happy to help, sorry it took so long, I've never used CodeIgnite before and everyone else appears to be asleep.  I've updated my answer with the solution in case anybody wishes to know what was wrong.  Wipe the `var_dump()s` and the URL from `config.php` from your question to keep your client out of search engines with this question, there is still history so there isn't total anonimity, but it helps mainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the new domain have the subdomain "system" setup?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
```

**UPDATE**

After a fair bit of debugging the problem was found to be some odd CGI setup with Apache on the server that was not setting any of the variables that CodeIgniter checks in the way it wished.

Modifying the `URI` class method `_fetch_uri_string()` `(system/libraries/URI.php:92;v1.7.2)` to look at `$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']` directly when present rather than any other variable solved the issue.  `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` mirrors this variable rather than being a sub-part of it as CodeIgniter expects.

**UPDATE 2**

There is an easier solution that I just discovered.

Changing `$config['uri_protocol']` in `system/application/config/config.php` to `ORIG_PATH_INFO` has the same effect.  Yes, I should have RTFM'd, but I never use CodeIgniter.

Comment: i checked the cpanel for the old site, and there are no sub domains defined.

Comment: @Jason, I assume that means the first two lines of that .htaccess (after RewriteBase) can go, as that is restricting to URIs starting with `system.`